# In R, how can I run a Spearman rank correlation using survey data?

Tags: r, correlation, survey, ordinal-data, spearman-rho

I know that using the survey package to account for complex survey data, I can use the `svycor()` function from the `jtools` library to run Pearson correlations.

But how can I run a rank correlation on data from a survey design?

Comment: A Spearman correlation is a Pearson correlation done on the ranks, so to obtain the correlation you can rank the data and use svycor(). The p-value will not be accurate, perhaps you can use bootstrapping?

Comment: Many thanks, Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to estimate the population Spearman correlation, then you can't just take the (weighted) correlation of the ranks, because the sample ranks don't have any consistent relationship to the population ranks. For example, if your two variables have long right tails and those tails are under-sampled relative to the main body of the distribution, the population ranks  for the largest observations are likely to be outliers; the sample ranks obviously wouldn't be.  So the population Spearman correlation isn't  as robust a statistic as we're used to. However, if you want to estimate it, that's what you want -- and most of the time, the estimated population ranks and the sample ranks will be pretty similar (apart from a scale factor)

For the population Spearman correlation you want the same rank transformation that the rank tests in the `survey` package use. We define the ranks by their relationship to the cumulative distribution function: under simple random sampling, the CDF takes values at the observations of $1/n, 2/n,\dots,n/n$, which are the ranks divided by the sample size.

We define the population estimated ranks as the values of the estimated population CDF times the estimated population size.

So:

```
svyrank<-function(formula, design){
    mf <- model.frame(formula, model.frame(design), na.action = na.fail)
    y<-mf[,1]
    ii <- order(y)
    n <- length(y)
    rankhat <- numeric(n)
    w <- weights(design, "sampling")
    rankhat[ii] <- ave(cumsum(w[ii]) - w[ii]/2, factor(y[ii]))
    rankhat
}
```

You can now use `svycor`, or `svyvar` followed by `svycontrast` if you want standard errors or folowed by `cov2cor` if you don't.   The rank transformation isn't a problem for the standard error estimation. The function as I've written it doesn't handle missing data, but does handle ties in the value.

Alternatively, you might want the sample Spearman correlation, which is just the sample Spearman correlation and doesn't need anything special.